# Converting data table to suitable javascript object (C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization, datatable

Short question:

Given table based data (such as SQL results), what is the most *accepted* method of converting this into a specific json string / js objectstring with C#?

Scenario:

I have a web page using d3.js to general graphical reports. For the data, I call an API which executes a stored procedure and returns the result set. I need a way of converting that data into a suitable json object which can easily be processed within my d3 report.

Example:

With the following table being returned by my stored procedure

[image]

What would be the most suitable kind of object to convert this data into for use with javascript / d3, and how would one go about achieving that?

What I've tried:

Since my API is written in C#, I've tried using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method, as below.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlDataAdapter sql = new SqlDataAdapter(getData))
{
    sql.Fill(dt);
}

returnStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

Which produces a simple  array, one item per row of data, for example:

```
[
    {
        "Group": "Group01", "TrueFalse": 1, "SubGroup": "SubGroup01", "Owner": "ME"
    },
    {
        "Group": "Group01", "TrueFalse": 1, "SubGroup": "SubGroup02", "Owner": "ME"
    },
    {
        "Group": "Group01", "TrueFalse": 0, "SubGroup": "SubGroup02", "Owner": "You"
    },
    {
        "Group": "Group01", "TrueFalse": 1, "SubGroup": "SubGroup03, "Owner": "You"
    },
    {
        "Group": "Group02", "TrueFalse": 0, "SubGroup": "SubGroup01", "Owner": "Someone"
    },
    // etc...
]
```

While its quite possible to work with this, I don't know if it's the best way of going about doing so, or whether we can create an object that's more suitable. If you can give any pointers on best practises, and possible examples, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of preference issue and perhaps consistency in your data model. What you have there is perhaps the preferred method as it is easy to iterate through while knowing the object structure in the array. Another way of doing it, and is harder to understand if you are an incoming developer, is to have an array for each column in the table and iterating by the index of the array to get the values. This would require more code and is less readable. So rather than indexing each field for each iteration through the array, you simply have objects that have a consistent structure, even if a field in the object is empty, which leads to another issue with the array-per-column approach: you would have to be absolutely sure that a field cannot be empty. Otherwise, your indexing counts will not be consistent.

Long story short, what you have there is semantically the most appropriate. Table columns equate to fields in your object, and the JSON object equates to a row in your table.I hope this makes sense to you and helps out.